# Select Spatial version from duplicated rows SQL

Tags: sql

I have SQL Table Like that

```
  Name         WID
----------  ----------
 name1         1
 name1         2
 name1         3
 name2         1
 name3         1
 name4         1
 name4         2
```

How I can get only the version before the last version as this

```
  Name         WID
----------  ----------
 name1         2
 name2         1
 name3         1
 name4         1
```

Using SQL Query

Comment: `name2         1` is the last version though, not the version before the last.

Comment: And which DBMS are you using, SQL-Server, Oracle, SQLite, Postgres? There are many and the answer will differ.

Comment: about name2 there no version for it, it only have one row, and i need to get it in the result, i need the version before the last version in case there is more than one version
And I use SQL Sever 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reach to the Query to get the result as I need

```
SELECT E.Name, E.WID 
FROM
(
    SELECT Name, MAX(WID) AS WID FROM MyTAble WHERE WID IN (2,1)
    GROUP BY Name
) AS ViewVersionIDs
INNER JOIN MyTable AS E ON ViewVersionIDs.Name = E.Name 
AND ViewVersionIDs.WID = E.WID
ORDER BY E.Name
```

If I need the only second Version I make the WID condition `WID IN (2,1)`
If i need the only third Version I make the WID condition `WID IN (3,2,1)`

And So on ...